# wkhtmltopdf : page load issue, blocked to 90%

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I m using wkhtmltopdf using the .net import.

When I try to render a PDF from a internal webpage, I have sometimes issue : the load of the page is blocked to 90%.

The page is using jquery.ajax to load data. When I have more than 1 ajax call, the bug occurs else the pdf is render well.

I try Pechkin and TuesPechkin but same issue.

Also interesting part, I add a break point on the last ajax call (c# service function) and the break point is reached.

Do you have an idea why I get this error ?

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue. The reason why wkhtmltopdf never finish is because the web page never complete loading. The reason why the page never complete loading is because it is running a signalR browser link.

All i had to do was to disable the signalR browser link and it works.

To disable the browser link, add the line below to appSettings in your web.config file

```
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
```